# Prevent link/file system traversal in swagger-parser

Tags: java, swagger, openapi

We are using https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-parser to validate swagger docs uploaded by users. I believe swagger can link to external docs or urls for schema definitions or other resources, which poses a security risk to our app. How can I disable link or file system traversal in swagger parser?